# Send POST request as Google forms response

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-forms

I want to send my answer programmatically, using Java. I want to send my response when there is inputs.

However, if there is a selection or a date picker, I can't find the name.

For example, [here is a link to my form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5jky_1lshaP8Ju7kNLGPVCcBvdJcqTMPVxuLW5zRFpPj87Q/viewform)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some code (at least the most relevant part) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an calender to pick a date from, this should work:

```
<form method="post">
 What is your birthday
 <input type="date" name="birthday" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```